# system.unauthorizedaccessexception access to the path ..... is denied

Tags: vb.net, exception, system.xml

I am running a system.xml.xmltextwriter() method in vb.net and everytime it tries to run i get a "system.unauthorizedaccessexception access to the path (FilePath) is denied."

I have been to through this file path giving all folders and the file full control access rights to "Everyone" (i know you shouldn't from a security point of view but i'm just trying to solve the problem at the moment).

If anyone has any other ideas as to what the problem could be it'd be much appreciated

Comment: What is the path you are trying to write to?  Thats a rather key element, no?

Comment: its a local C: drive path... the path is correct i've double and triple checked it. it's writing to an xml file

Comment: There are plenty of places you can't write to on C: - be more specific as to the path you are writing to.